# Recover value of field in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry for the english, i'm french student :(

I would like create a comment system with AngularJS for a project.

I would like recover a value of an object who is in ng-repeat loop.

JSON : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzj557dnogzOd0ZUMnZ1cWZLSFU/edit?usp=sharing

HTML :

```
<section ng-controller='AnnouncesCtrl' ng-show='!showActions' ng-swipe-left='showActions=true'>

<header class='header'>
    <span class="return"><a href='#practice' class='title_link'>6</a></span> Petites annonces <span class="new"><a href='#newAnnounce'>8</a></span>
</header>

<div class='loader' ng-show='loader'></div>

<section class='panel'>
    <div ng-repeat='a in dept.announce' class='announces'>
        <span class='title'>{{a.name}}</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="date">{{a.date}}</span>
        <hr>
        <span class="msg">{{a.desc}}</span>
        <hr>
        <div class="showrep" ng-click="show=true" ng-show='!show'>Montrer les réponses</div>
        <div class="allrep" ng-show="show" ng-repeat='answer in a.answers'>{{answer}}<br/></div>
        <div class="formrep">
            <form ng-submit='addComments()'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Écrire une réponse'><input type='submit' ng-click='a.btn={{a.id}}' value='Répondre'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS :

```
function AnnouncesCtrl($scope,$http,$rootScope,$location){

$scope.getInfos=function(){

    var dept="http://agence-pandor.fr/getAnnounces/index.php";

    $scope.loader=true;
    $http.get(dept)
        .success(deptSuccess)
        .error(function(){
            $scope.loader=false;
            alert('Impossible de récupérer le numéro étudiant. Veuillez vous reconnecter');
            $location.url("/connexion"); // On redirige
    })
}

deptSuccess=function(response){
    $scope.loader=false;
    $scope.dept=response;
}

$scope.getInfos();

$scope.addComments=function(){
    alert($scope.dept.announce.btn);
}
```

}

Screenshot :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzj557dnogzOUDlfNWR3eEthQzA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what your project is about (I don't know French). You are iterating over the array "announce" which is supposedly a property of "dept". When you type:

```
ng-repeat = 'a in dept.announce'
```

you are creating a temporary variable "a" in the scope that is meant for ng-repeat (like counter variable in a for loop).

If "btn" is supposed to be a unique value, then use:

```
ng-click = "btn = a.id"
```

or if "btn" is specific to each value of "a in announce", use:

```
ng-click = "btn[$index] = a.id";
```

You can get the value of btn in your JS file by using $scope.btn